# Is there an instance Stream Handle IO Char for Text.Parsec.Stream?

Tags: haskell, handle, parsec

I'm parsing a fairly large file, and I'd like to periodically update a progress bar to indicate how much of it I've parsed thus far.

The most direct way I can think to do this is use `ParsecT` as a monad transformer for `IO` so I can lift printing the progres bar updates, and use a `Handle` as a stream provider so I can check the progress using `hFileSize` and `hTell`.

So that means I need an instance `Stream Handle IO Char`.  It shouldn't be hard to roll my own (using `hGetChar`) but I figured I'd see if one existed already, to handle any unforseen issues (like whether I'll need to insert some buffering for speed).

Comment: another unforseen issue: [backtracking!](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-February/039059.html)

Comment: Can you query the file size once ahead of time and just use the usual lazy IO + `Stream String m Char` instance (which already tracks a `SourcePos` for you)? It might be a bit racy, but not more racy than the proposal you made in your question.

Comment: Daniel Wagner: It looks like `SourcePos` doesn't track absolute offset, just line/column, so I'd have to precompute the line count.

Comment: You have complete control over the `SourcePos`, so you can store the absolute offset in, say, the column number if you want.

Comment: Daniel Wagner: Yes, but that would require me preventing Parsec from resetting the column counter automatically when it matches a `\n`.  Regardless, I wound up [counting lines](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Wc#Data.ByteString.Lazy) and using the SourcePos's `sourceLine` to show progress, so if you want to upgrade your suggestion to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hack would be to check the size of the file ahead of time. Then, as you're parsing, check the `SourcePos` that parsec makes available to see how far you've gotten. The downside to this is that if you want to track actual byte count (so that you can use the file system's knowledge of file size to avoid traversing the file twice), you will have to reimplement the base parsers by hand using [`tokenPrim`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3atokenPrim). The parser combinators shouldn't need to be reimplemented, though.

Alternately, you can traverse the file twice and use the line count (computing during the first traversal) as an estimate of how far you've gotten.